# from __future__ import absolute_import as _absolute_import error, tensorflow doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, spyder

I'm working on deep learning with tensorflow in spyder, but i'm new.
Suddenly tensorflow stopped working and now `import tensorflow as tf` line gives the error that is below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import as _absolute_import
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My other working projects also no longer work. I searched for the error but i couldnt find useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax to import module `from __future__ import absolute_import` but here since you have not put in the complete detail of error, it can be an issue with python version as `TensorFlow` is currently being supported till `Python3.8`. [Details](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Comment: not only absolutue, also division,printfunction, distutils, inspect, os,site, sys are also have underscore like _distutils. I delete these underscores but still it is not working.

Comment: @snk Above what you asked is ```syntax error```. Even if TensorFlow or say any other library is not present then it will not give you syntax error but will throw ```import error```. Post your piece of code and the complete error trace

Comment: i tried to compile code line by line and in "import tensorflow as tf
" line the error that is below occured.
runfile('C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Deep-MIMO-Detection-master/Deep-MIMO-Detection-master/DeepMimo.py', wdir='C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Deep-MIMO-Detection-master/Deep-MIMO-Detection-master')
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 17
    from __future__ import absolute_import as _absolute_import
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which python version you are using?

Comment: I'm using 3.6.10 version.